# Opencart 1.5.6 -> Opencart 2.1

Tags: opencart

Импортировал дамп базы данных таблиц (oc_category,oc_category_description,oc_category_path,oc_category_to_store) версии 1.5.6 в версию 2.1.0.2.1.
Импорт прошел успешно, но теперь вот незадача.
В администраторской панели, категории не отображаются. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не отображаются категории в админке? Как устранить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте таблицу `oc_category_to_store` . Скорее всего у Вас не совпадает `store_id` для текущего магазина и импортированных категорий. Нужный `id` можете в `oc_setting` посмотреть. Если я прав, то надо будет просто обновить ID магазина для категорий.

Comment: Да нет вроде, в default версии стоит 0, и на этой аналогично стоит 0.

Comment: Как правило при переносе возникают проблемы либо с ID магазина, либо с ID языка, либо с родительской категорией. Как [здесь](http://vpsvds.ru/blog/2015/03/20/propala-categoriya-tovarov.html) например. Можете экспорт базы сделать и показать?